# Use complex integration to evaluate

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

[image]

For this particular question, I am a bit confused about what this question wants me to do. It seems like the result is already given and x is not even a complex number...Hope for any clarification or suggestion, thanks in advance!

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [contour integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration) might be a place to start.  If you have further questions, edit them into to your Question.

Comment: At a glance I'd try this: Replace $x$ by a complex $z$. Use semi-circular contour and residue theorem. For the second integral do the same but use even integrand property.

Comment: use the method of residues to prove that those are the values of integrals. one of the useful applications of compex integration is to be able to compute real integrals (often easier) so the question wants you to practice that

Comment: but actually we did cover residue theorem in lectures...

Comment: It seems that if you covered the residue theorem, then these are perfect examples to help you feel comfortable with the calculations.

Comment: I think you should be using [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) by now

Answer (score 0):

For a).

Note that you can rewrite:
$$
z^6+1 = (z-e^{i \pi/6})(z-e^{3i \pi/6})(z-e^{5i \pi/6})(z+e^{i \pi/6})(z+e^{3i \pi/6})(z+e^{5i \pi/6})
$$
Observe that the above equation tells you the singular points of the function 
$$
\frac{z^2}{z^6+1} = \frac{z^2}{(z-e^{i \pi/6})(z-e^{3i \pi/6})(z-e^{5i \pi/6})(z+e^{i \pi/6})(z+e^{3i \pi/6})(z+e^{5i \pi/6})}
$$
Choose a contour $C_R$ as the semicircle: $z(t) = Re^{it}$ for $0 \le t \le \pi$ and the closed contour $l$ as $[-R,R] + C_R$. Eventually, you can obtain the value of the desired integral by letting $R \to \infty$.

Now, it is your work to try to apply the Residue theorem to finish the answer.

Comment: But we have not covered residue theorem in lectures...Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: In the comment, you said that you did cover residue theorem in lectures. I don't quite know how to do it without using residue theorem....